# Can't read binary file past some point

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, binary-data

I need to parse several binary files containing 2-byte integer values. Since I've recently figured I have no idea of how the streams in C++ work, I decided to try them instead of good ole `fopen(); fread()`. So I've got this function:

```
void work( string filename )
{
    ifstream f( filename );

    if ( !f.is_open() )
        throw exception( ("File not found: "+filename).c_str() );

    //first 128 bytes are header that shouldn't be parsed
    f.seekg( 0, f.end );
    uint64_t length = f.tellg();
    f.seekg( 128, f.beg );
    if ( !f.good() )
        throw exception( "Couldn't skip the 128byte header" );
    length -= 128;


    uint8_t buf[4];
    vector<int> first, second;
    size_t v = 0;
    int a = -1;
    int b = -1;

    while ( !f.eof() )
    {
        f.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 4 );

        if ( !f.good() )
        {
            cerr << "Couldn't read two 2byte values: read " << f.gcount() << "/4 bytes" << endl
                << "Bytes parsed: " << v << "/" << length << endl
                << "last 4 bytes: "
                << hex << +buf[0] << " " << +buf[1] << " | " << +buf[2] << " " << +buf[3] << endl;
            string s;
            if ( f.bad() )
                s = "BAD";
            else if ( f.fail() )
                s = "FAIL";
            else
                s = "WAT";
            throw exception( s.c_str() );
        }

        //only first 10 bits of values actually matter
        a = get10bit( buf[0], buf[1] );
        first.push_back( a );
        b = get10bit( buf[2], buf[3] );
        second.push_back( b );
        v += 4;
    }

    doStuff( first, second );
}
```

However for some reason, the cycle stops after reading only a part of a file, so I get next output:

> Couldn't read two 2byte values: read 0/4 bytes
>
> Bytes parsed: 88/1000000
>
> last 4 bytes: 57 f0 | 3d 0
>
> Exception: FAIL

I supposed that the problem was with my incorrect use of streams, so I tried to switch to `fread()`, but result was the same. I then tested both version of the program on several other files, guessing that there's something wrong with this one... But to my surprise, `f.fail()` eventually triggers at whatever file I'm trying to parse! The amount of successfully parsed bytes is different for each file, though.

As my dad advised, I then tried to read bigger chunks of data (and even whole files) instead of multiple 4-byte portions, but that didn't help too. Now I'm completely out of ideas.

Just in case: the contents (in hexademical) of my original file, skipping the header. I've highlighted in bold the last pair of values that was read correctly.

> E7 FF  4C 00  FD FF  01 00    2A 00  ED FF    0A 00  43 00
>
> 12 00  26 00  53 00  DB FF    F3 FF  0C 00    EC FF  50 00
>
> 6E 00  10 00  37 00  D1 FF    FA FF  0D 00    29 00  44 00
>
> 4E 00  2F 00  15 00  1C 00    9F FF  36 00    35 FE  ED FF
>
> E4 FB  C4 FF  C1 F4  23 00    E6 EA  39 00    73 EB  D5 FF
>
> 99 EF  DF FF  **57 F0  3D 00**    1A F3  2C 00    97 F5  E7 EF

Comment: If you do not know C is a different language than C++, do not ad C tag!

Comment: If os == windows, or os == macos you should use "ios::binary" flag, like this std::ifstream f( "path/to/file", std::ios::binary );

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are opening the file in text mode while you should open it in binary mode. In text mode, the symbol `^Z` (ASCII 26 = 0x1A) is the EOF (end of file) control code.

Change the code to:

```
ifstream f( filename, ifstream::binary );
```

Comment: ...I knew that it must be some simple little thing that I missed. Works now, thank you.